# inheritance/overruling of .htaccess files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, inheritance, webserver, overriding

I've read some answers about inheritance of options set in `.htaccess` files, but I'm still unclear on this.

### Short version:

Does an `.htaccess` in a subfolder replace only the rules contained in the subfolder's `.htaccess`, **or** does it *completely* replace the root-folder's `.htaccess`?

---

### Longer example:

Let's say I have 2 `.htaccess` files:

- `.htaccess` in my `/` (**root**) folder:

  ```
  DefaultLanguage en-CA
  RewriteEngine on  
  RewriteCond yadda yadda
  RewriteRule blah blah blah
  ```
- `.htaccess` in **`/mySubfolder`**:

  ```
  DefaultLanguage fr-CA
  ```

| `.htaccess` in `/` (**root**) folder | `.htaccess` in **`/mySubfolder`** |
| --- | --- |
| `DefaultLanguage en-CA` `RewriteEngine on` `RewriteCond yadda yadda` `RewriteRule blah blah blah` | `DefaultLanguage fr-CA` |

...in this case, I assume:

- the **language** will be `en-CA` for the entire website ***except*** `mySubfolder` (and it's subfolders) will be `fr-CA`, but,
- the **rewrite** will still be applied to the entire website including `mySubfolder`.

...**or**, does `/mySubfolder/.htaccess` cancel out the **entire** root `.htaccess`?

---

Also I *think* [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is irrelevant because I'm not using any `<Directory>` sections... *right?*

Comment: `DefaultLanguage fr-CA` directive will be set for the sub-directory tree starting from `mySubfolder`.

Comment: The `AllowOverride` is _not_ irrelevant, you need to enable the interpretation / consideration of such distributed configuration files. You can use it only once in the central configuration though.

Comment: About inheritance: your concept is wrong. distributed configuration files will not at all overwrite each other or "cancel out" each other. That is not how things work. Instead they are processed one after another in the order they are found when stepping down the folder hierarchy while processing an incoming request.